# knockouts change attributes and check criteria

Tags: knockout.js

I have a multi-select list with 3 menus. I have referenced the KO site and I am trying to make 3 of the menus "options" display differently inside of each one. Everytime i make changes, it changes all of them. I am sure an observable needs to be duplicated and changed somewhere, I am just unsure.

My goal is to run an if statement that checks if the criteria matches x,x,x

```js
function Attribute(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = data.Id;
    self.Name = data.Name;
}

function Attribute2(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = data.Id;
    self.Name = data.Name;
}


// Individual Row in Table

function Criteria(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Attributes = ko.observableArray(data.Attributes);
}

function Criteria2(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Attributes2 = ko.observableArray(data.Attributes2);
}
// Represent the ViewModel for attributes.
function CriteriaViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // Catalog Data
    self.availableAttributes = window.ko.observableArray([]);
    self.availableAttributes(ko.utils.arrayMap(rawAttributes, function(item) { return new Attribute(item); }));

 self.availableAttributes2 = window.ko.observableArray([]);
    self.availableAttributes2(ko.utils.arrayMap(rawAttributes2, function(item) { return new Attribute2(item); }));
    
    // Editable Data
    self.criterion = window.ko.observableArray([]);
    self.criterion(ko.utils.arrayMap(rawCriterion, function (item) { return new Criteria(item); }));
    
    self.criterion2 = window.ko.observableArray([]);
    self.criterion2(ko.utils.arrayMap(rawCriterion2, function (item) { return new Criteria2(item); }));
}

function CriteriaViewModel2() {
    var self = this;

    // Catalog Data
   
 self.availableAttributes2 = window.ko.observableArray([]);
    self.availableAttributes2(ko.utils.arrayMap(rawAttributes2, function(item) { return new Attribute2(item); }));
    
    // Editable Data
    self.criterion = window.ko.observableArray([]);
    self.criterion(ko.utils.arrayMap(rawCriterion, function (item) { return new Criteria(item); }));
    
    self.criterion2 = window.ko.observableArray([]);
    self.criterion2(ko.utils.arrayMap(rawCriterion2, function (item) { return new Criteria2(item); }));
}


var rawAttributes = [
    {
        Id:'1',
        Name:'text1'
    },
    {
        Id:'2',
        Name:'text2'
    },
    
    {
        Id:'3',
        Name:'text3'
    },
       
    {
        Id:'4',
        Name:'text4'
    }
];

var rawAttributes2 = [
    {
        Id:'1',
        Name:'tedsdd'
    },
    {
        Id:'2',
        Name:'text2'
    },
    
    {
        Id:'3',
        Name:'text3'
    },
       
    {
        Id:'4',
        Name:'text4'
    }
];

var rawCriterion = [
    {
        Attributes : []   
    },
       
];

var rawCriterion2 = [
    {
        Attributes : []   
    },
       
];

ko.applyBindings(new CriteriaViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!----Set 1--->
<div data-bind="foreach: criterion">    
    <select class="selectedAttributes"
            data-bind="options: $root.availableAttributes, 
                        selectedOptions: Attributes, 
                        optionsText: 'Name', 
                        optionsValue: 'Id'"
            multiple
            size="6">
    </select>
</div>

<div data-bind="foreach: criterion">
    <div data-bind='text:"Criteria " + $index()'></div>
    <ul data-bind='foreach:Attributes'>
        <li data-bind='text:$data'></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-------------Set 2-------------->
<div data-bind="foreach: criterion2">    
    <select class="selectedAttributes2"
            data-bind="options: $root.availableAttributes, 
                        selectedOptions: Attributes2, 
                        optionsText: 'Name', 
                        optionsValue: 'Id'"
            multiple
            size="6">
    </select>
</div>


<div data-bind="foreach: criterion2">
    <div data-bind='text:"Criteria2 " + $index()'></div>
    <ul data-bind='foreach:Attributes2'>
        <li data-bind='text:$data'></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "I am trying to make 3 of the menus "options" display differently inside of each one" You're trying to make the options different yet you have each options bound to the same array

Comment: thanks, didn realize that

Comment: you can post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to make the options different yet you have each options binding bound to the same array.  They're each going to show the options of that array.

If you want the options to be a subset of that array, do something like so:

```
var arrayToDeriveFrom = ko.utils.arrayMap(rawAttributes, function (item)
    return new Attribute(item);
});

var availableAttributes1 = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(arrayToDeriveFrom, function (item) {
        // do filtering here
    });
});

<select class="selectedAttributes1"
        data-bind="options: $root.availableAttributes1, 
                    selectedOptions: Attributes1, 
                    optionsText: 'Name', 
                    optionsValue: 'Id'"
        multiple
        size="6">
</select>
```